# Constrain a database table entry based on data in another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two database tables which are related:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicKeyword] 
(
    [Id]      SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    [Keyword] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Volume]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [PageId]  SMALLINT     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicKeyword] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicCluster] 
(
    [KeywordId] SMALLINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicCluster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KeywordId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_TopicCluster_TopicKeyword] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicKeyword] ([Id])
);
```

As you can see `TopicCluster` references `TopicKeyword` using `KeywordId`.

However, I need to ensure further integrity on the `TopicCluster` table.

The `PageID` in the `TopicKeyword` table can be repeated multiple times, but only one keyword per `PageId` should be allowed in the `TopicCluster` table.

For instance:

**TopicKeyword**

Id, PageId

- 1, 5
- 2, 6
- 3, 5 // 5 is repeated

**TopicCluster**

KeywordId

- 1
- 2
- 3 // should not be allowed because 1 already references PageId: 5

I've created a solution, but I'm no SQL guy, so I'm unsure whether it's the right approach in this instance. Here's are the tables again, reworked to include new constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicKeyword] 
(
    [Id]      SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    [Keyword] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Volume]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [PageId]  SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicKeyword] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO

// New
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TopicKeyword_Id_PageId]
ON [dbo].[TopicKeyword]([Id] ASC, [PageId] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicCluster] 
(
    [KeywordId] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [PageId]    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicCluster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KeywordId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_TopicCluster_PageId] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([PageId] ASC), // New
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TopicCluster_TopicKeyword] FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicKeyword] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TopicCluster_TopicKeyword2] FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId], [PageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicKeyword] ([Id], [PageId]) // New
);
GO

// New
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TopicCluster_KeywordId_PageId]
ON [dbo]
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: If `PageID` needs to o be unique, have you considered making a Unique Index on the column?

Comment: PageID isn't unique in the TopicKeyword table - a page can be associated with multiple keywords - but it can only be associated with one 'Cluster'. There's a unique index on the revised solution but it's on the TopicCluster table, not the Topic KeywordTable.

Comment: Then put the unique index on the PageId and the other column that makes a combination of being unique. I assume PageId and ClusterId, which seems to have been omitted from your sample (guessing we have an overly simplified version).

Answer (score 0):

I cleared your script:

```
CREATE TABLE TopicKeyword 
(
    Id      smallint     NOT NULL,
    Keyword varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Volume  int          NOT NULL,
    PageId  smallint     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TopicKeyword PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT UK_TopicKeyword UNIQUE (Id, PageId) -- to create FOREIGN KEY in TopicCluster
)
GO

CREATE TABLE TopicCluster 
(
    KeywordId smallint NOT NULL,
    PageId    smallint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_TopicCluster PRIMARY KEY (KeywordId), -- to exclude duplicates in KeywordId
    CONSTRAINT UK_TopicCluster_PageId UNIQUE (PageId),  -- to exclude duplicates in PageId

    CONSTRAINT FK_TopicCluster_TopicKeyword
          FOREIGN KEY (KeywordId, PageId)
          REFERENCES TopicKeyword (Id, PageId) -- to prevent pairs of KeywordId&PageId which not in TopicKeyword
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL is a good for your use case.

If i have something bad to say about it, it would be the PageId column that should be present in the TopicKeyword table only (duplication of data), you can use SQL JOIN statments to get the PageId when needed.

If im guessing right your TopicKeyword table should store one unique combination of (keyword and page) per row, for that i would do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicKeyword] 
(
    [Id]      SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    [Keyword] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Volume]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [PageId]  SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicKeyword] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_TopicKeyword] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Keyword] ASC, [PageId] ASC)
);
GO
```

The PK will be used for reference and the unique constraint will ensure the unique combination of (keyword and page) per row.

For the second part you want to store in the cluster table keywords that were associated with only one page, for that i would do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_IsPageIdUnique
(
    @KeywordId SMALLINT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsPageIdUnique BIT
    DECLARE @PageIdCount INT

    SELECT @PageIdCount = COUNT(k2.[PageId])
    FROM [TopicKeyword] k1
    INNER join [TopicKeyword] k2 ON k2.[PageId] = k1.[PageId]
    WHERE k1.[Id] = @KeywordId

    IF (@PageIdCount = 1)
        SET @IsPageIdUnique = 1
    ELSE
        SET @IsPageIdUnique = 0

    RETURN @IsPageIdUnique
END
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TopicCluster] 
(
    [KeywordId] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TopicCluster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KeywordId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TopicCluster_TopicKeyword] FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TopicKeyword] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT CK_TopicCluster CHECK (dbo.FN_IsPageIdUnique(KeywordId))
);
GO
```

The check constraint will help you enforce the uniqueness of your cluster data based on another table data that will be calculated with the scalar function FN_IsPageIdUnique.